# Как объединить несколько выражений в одно?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(".full_link_open").click(function(){
if ($(this).parents('.short_news').hasClass("open_news")) {
    $(this).parents('.short_news').toggleClass("open_news");
} else {
    В этой строчке.removeClass("open_news");    
    $(this).parents('.short_news').toggleClass("open_news");    
    }
});
```

На странице получается есть несколько блоков которые работают под данным кодом.
Через this и parents, получается узнавать родителя short_news, этой кнопки. Однако в строчке removeClass, он удаляет все open_news со страницы (мне нужно чтобы удалял именно из этого блока). 
В принципе, если добавить

```
$(".full_block_top .short_news").removeClass("open_news");
```

то вопрос решить удается, однако тогда нужно делать 4 функции

пытался через

```
$(this).parents('.news_last .short_news').removeClass("open_news");
```

Но тут он удаляется только у родителя

Код html (таких на странице 4)

```
    <div class="full_block">
        <div class="news">
        <div class="news_first">
            <div class="short_news">
                <div class="info_news">
                    контент
                </div>
                <div class="full_info_news">
                        Контент
                    <div class="full_link full_link_open">
                        <a></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> // немного отличается
        </div>
        <div class="news_last">
            <div class="short_news">
                <div class="info_news">
                    контент
                </div>
                <div class="full_info_news">
                        Контент
                    <div class="full_link full_link_open">
                        <a></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="short_news">
                <div class="info_news">
                    контент
                </div>
                <div class="full_info_news">
                        Контент
                    <div class="full_link full_link_open">
                        <a></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, добавил

Comment: @Alex, для каждой функции будем метки создавать? Так скоро, в таком случае, под вопросами будут простыни меток писать, по количеству функций упомянутых в вопросе.

Comment: @Visman метки созданы, чтобы пользователи более менее понимали о чем вопрос, т.к. много вопросов с меткой jquery и/или javascript, а из заголовка непонятно о содержимом вопроса. Разумеется неправильно создавать кучу бесполезных меток, но добавить 1-3 полезных меток(конкретизирующих вопрос) при наличии лишь общих меток(jquery, javascript) не будет лишним.

Comment: @Alex, и на сколько полезны эти две метки? Они бессмысленны. Сходите на http://stackoverflow.com и посмотрите какие там метки для jquery существуют. Удалил.

Comment: @Visman как могут быть бессмысленны метки если они прямо говорят о чем вопрос? И это при том, что относятся метки к конкретной теме, а не ко всему подряд, как, например, тег **[регулярные-выражения](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)**.

Comment: @Alex, если вы считаете, что я не прав удалив эти метки, то обратитесь к модераторам с этим вопросом.

Comment: @Alex, основное назначение меток - это разбиение вопросов на группы по темам, фильтрация вопросов по этим темам при поиске и подписка на отфильтрованные вопросы. Чтобы пользователи понимали, о чем вопрос, лучше хорошо сформулировать вопрос. Не стоит использовать метку для описания деталей реализаций и очень узких понятий. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Comment: @Nofate спасибо за уточнение

Comment: @Visman спасибо за корректировку)

Comment: @Alex, всегда пожалуйста. Если что-то непонятно - не стесняйтесь спрашивать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".full_link_open").click(function(){
    if ($(this).parents('.short_news').hasClass('open_news')) {
        $(this).parents('.short_news').toggleClass('open_news');
    } 
    else{ 
        $(this).parents('.full_block').children('.short_news').removeClass('open_news');
        //или используем .find() 
        //$(this).parents('.full_block').find('.short_news').removeClass('open_news');
        $(this).parents('.short_news').toggleClass('open_news');    
    }
});
```

Comment: Немного не то, он будет удалять у родительского элемента open_news, а нужно у всех (в блоке)

Comment: @lingvo потому что не было html и было не очень понятно как расположены элементы. изменили ответ.

Comment: Спасибо! Чего-то я туплю, вроде все так просто.